# `breadcrumb` - accumulating, not resetting on move out of page

Tags: angular, router, breadcrumbs, angular8

I am trying to build a `breadcrumb` with angular router. the issue is, I am not able to reset the values on user come out of the page.

1. when page is refreshed breadcrumb not shows unless i use routing
2. breadcrumb not resetting, it just accumulating all routes i visit.

how to fix it? any one help me?

ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RoutesRecognized, NavigationEnd, Params, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';
import { IBOBreadCrumb } from './../../models/models';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
    selector: 'bread-crumbs',
    templateUrl: './bread-crumbs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bread-crumbs.component.scss']
})
export class BreadCrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

    breadcrumbs = [];

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.breadcrumbs = [];

        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
            .pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute))
            .pipe(map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
                return route;
            }))
            .pipe(filter(route => route.outlet === PRIMARY_OUTLET))
            .subscribe(route => {

                const snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
                const url = snapshot.url;
                const routeData = route.snapshot.data;

                const label = routeData['breadcrumb'];
                const params = snapshot.root.params;

                this.breadcrumbs.push({
                    url: url,
                    label: label,
                    params: params
                });

            });



    }

}
```

html file:

```
<nav aria-label='breadcrumb'>
  <ol class='breadcrumb'>
    <li *ngFor='let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs'>
      <a [routerLink]='[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]' routerLinkActive='active'>{{ breadcrumb.label }}</a> ::|::
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Issue 1 is probably because your code runs when all navigation is already done - so nothing triggers. Issue 2 is easily solvable by moving this.breadcrumbs = []; inside the subscription..

Comment: And as an additional comment - why all the pipes?

Comment: Check this repo. Try using a service behind the breadcrumb.
https://angular-breadcrumb-demo.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Mike if I am wrong can you simplify my code

Comment: Sridar I have nested children,  so the issue raising